# Removing JavaFX TreeCell formating added with PseudoClass

Tags: css, treeview, javafx-8, pseudo-class

I am using a PseudoClass to change the formating of a JavaFx TreeCell depending on a condition given by the data in the tree cell. The following code works:

```
public class EmfTreeCellImpl extends TreeCell<EmfTreeNode> {

    PseudoClass AMBIGUOUS_FEATURE = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("ambiguous-feature");

    public EmfTreeCellImpl() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(EmfTreeNode item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty || item == null) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
            return;
        }
        setText(item.getLabel());
        setEditable(false);
        if (item instanceof EmfTreeNode.SingleAttributeNode) {
            EmfTreeNode.SingleAttributeNode san = (EmfTreeNode.SingleAttributeNode) item;
            //pseudoClassStateChanged(AMBIGUOUS_FEATURE, san.isAmbiguous());
            pseudoClassStateChanged(AMBIGUOUS_FEATURE, san.isAmbiguous());
        }
    }
}
```

The cells get highlighted correctly. The issue is that the highlight is "persisted" in the specific tree cell in the GUI. That is, if I collapse or expand other tree branches the highlight stays "in place" highlighting other cells that do not meet the condition. I thought the `setGraphic(null)` would remove the formatting.

To solve this I added an extra line to the updateItem to clear the formatting:

```
if (empty || item == null) {
    setText(null);
    setGraphic(null);
    pseudoClassStateChanged(AMBIGUOUS_FEATURE, false);
    return;
}
```

But somehow it feels I should only be either removing the format from the ones that have been formatted or using a more "global" clear.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you find your own solution lacking - if you set a pseudo-class on the `TreeCell` you have to clear it when it is no longer valid. Setting the graphic to `null` doesn't change the style of the `TreeCell` itself. I guess you could potentially set the style on the node used as graphic content, but that may not be possible in some cases, depending on your actual style.  As far as I know there is nothing wrong with removing a pseudo-class if it wasn't active - that's the point of using pseudo classes instead of style classes.

Comment: I guess I was just expecting a more "elegant" way. I guess there are very few resources out there that really explain the way JavaFX works behinds sceens and hence it is hard to appreciate if one's solution is inline with the framework philosophy.

Comment: I agree the documentation is somewhat lacking, and the framework philosophy may seem inconsistent at times.   Maybe something more elegant would be to use the built-in `empty` or `filled` pseudo-classes, so your CSS rule can be `:filled:ambiguous-feature`, which means it will never apply to empty cells. See the [JavaFX CSS Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#cell)

Comment: Great! If you post this as an answer I will be happy to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the solution proposed in the answer itself is perfectly valid, however a more concise way of handling it may be making use of the built-in `filled` pseudo-class of [`Cell`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#cell) which is applied automatically to any non-empty cell:

```
:filled:ambiguous-feature { 
    /* css-styling of non-empty ambiguous cells */ 
}
```